# Prevent Perf Name Demangling

Tags: linux, gdb, stack-trace, perf, demangler

I use `Perf` to extract callgraphs for an `evince` benchmark (which is written in `C++`). By default, `Perf` demangles function names in the callgraph. But this is not what is prefered. Because I feed function names to `GDB` which requires mangled names. Is there an option in `Perf` to prevent name demangling?

Comment: I found the option, just add `--no-demangle` switch to the command line. It works in both `perf script` and `perf report`.